# Use DataTable Compute method for a different locale?

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, localization

I'm using the `Compute` method to evaluate an expression. My current locale is `de-DE`. This is simply done by:

```
var dt = new DataTable() {
    Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
};

var v = dt.Compute(myExpression);
```

When I enter an expression such as:

> 30.5 / 2.25

The expression is evaluated correctly.

However, when as my locale is different, I need to enter the above expression as:

> 30,5 / 2,25

The expression is not evaluated as expected.

How do I get the `Compute` method to evaluate expression correctly for the given locale?

Comment: Seems not possible. Looking at the source code, the `ExpressionParser` creates a `ConstNode` and for `ValueType.Float` it calls `Convert.ToDouble(constant, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);`. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/Filter/ExpressionParser.cs,ea0429d35545a152

Answer (score 0):

Easy, crude workaround that works:

```
var dt = new DataTable();

var temp = myExpression.Replace(".", string.Empty).Replace(",", ".");
var v = dt.Compute(temp, string.Empty);
```

Won't work when changing locales. Might be expanded to handle locales.